# Change pip build directory from read-only file system

Tags: python, installation, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I have a repo on a read-only file system (I cannot get write access), so I can't make changes to it at all. But I want to run `pip install .` and install any needed files to my home location `~`. Here is a snippet of errors I get (the repo has a `setup.py` file)

```
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      error: could not create 'build': Read-only file system
```

I have tried add folders in my home directory and using their location with [flags](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/) `-t`, `--root`, `--src` or `--prefix` but I get the same error. And ideas on how to install it locally?

Comment: I'm afraid you need to copy the directory to a more open filesystem. If it's a Git repo you can ask Git to copy (clone): `pip install git+file:/path/to/read-only-repo`

Comment: Ok that sounds like an answer, thanks. I realized I can copy the repo to another directory, I think the large weights it uses don't need to be copied also.

Comment: You need to copy all the files that will be packed into the resulting distribution and installed.

Comment: Yeah the whole repo can be installed, never mind the mention of weights, it's a repo that uses them separetely

Comment: You can put that as an answer, saying it's not possible, in case other come across this dilemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experiments I didn't find a way to do that. I believe you need to copy the directory to a more open filesystem and install from the copy.

If it's a Git repo you can ask Git to copy (clone):

```
pip install git+file:/path/to/read-only-repo
```